# Pentaho DI Opening transformation: [null] in directory

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

guys!

I have problem with starting kettle job from server.
I have simple job with one trasformation. Trasformation is saved in the repository server.

[job in spoon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUGyX.png)

If i start job from Pentaho local machine, the job runs successful, but transformation didn't work.

Log(very detailed):

- Spoon - Starting job...
- Job_test - Start of job execution
- Job_test - exec(0, 0, START.0)
- START - Starting job entry
- Job_test - Starting entry [simple_upsert]
- Job_test - exec(1, 0, simple_upsert.0)
- simple_upsert - Starting job entry
  **- simple_upsert - Opening transformation: [null] in directory [/home/.../test]**
- simple_upsert - Loading transformation from repository [test_ms_sql] in directory [/home/.../test]
- Job_test - Starting entry [Success]
- Job_test - exec(2, 0, Success.0)
- Success - Starting job entry
- Job_test - Finished job entry [Success] (result=[true])
- Job_test - Finished job entry [simple_upsert] (result=[true])
- Job_test - Job execution finished
- Spoon - Job has ended.

Transformation is valid and located in directory [/home/.../test].
I tested running from local machine and pentaho server. In both cases there are same strokes and transformation didn't performed.
What does mean ***Opening transformation: [null]***? Why job doesn't see transformation? Transformation exactly located in this directory, i browse it in settings transformation.
Who know how it resolve?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem. I'm using PDI 8.2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help because the only hint to this issue i found, is [this forum post](https://forums.pentaho.com/archive/index.php/t-48611.html) from 12 years ago. If you are working with Repositories it seems that everytime you save the KTR, it changes it's ID inside the Repository, so you'd have to re-link it everytime. I doubt this is still an issue, as this post is from Verison 2.2 or earlier. Hope it helps.

Other possible solution, which i doubt you missed this, is the KTR call coded in the Job step ? I've experienced a similar 'Null' pointer by trying to run a Job with an empty KTR call.

Comment: thank for reply. Forum's post i've read, unfortunately, it's not my case, i use pdi 8.0 version. And if miss path to transformation it'd error. In my case job run succesed.